# Sort function in JavaScript does not give correct output for some cases?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I tried to use sort function to arrange the items in order to find the largest element in a number array.
In Chrome, inspect element and open the console.

```
>>var a = [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
>>undefined
>>a.sort()
>>(4) [1, 1000, 1001, 857] // no patern found.
```

Why did the numbers did not sort properly like they did for the other cases like these:

```
>>var b = [13, 27, 18, 26];
>>undefined
>>b.sort()
>>(4) [13, 18, 26, 27] // here the numbers are in ascending order.
```

Comment: The default comparator function compares values as strings, not numbers. You can pass your own comparator function.

Comment: From the docs: `The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default sort order treats the elements of the array as text, not numbers.

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: That's well understood. Do you suggest I will not be able to use this sort function and i have to write my own? what is the use of the sort function in that case ?

Comment: That's only a default, you can provide your own function which takes in two elements and decides which one should be placed first in the array. The documentation is quite thorough in explaining how that function should behave.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description